# Converting JSON object into array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I have tried to take the particular array value of key from a JSON object and store  that in an array which will be look like this.

**Example:**

```
var obj = { "1":{"class":2,"percent":0.99,"box":[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]},
            "2":{"class":2,"percent":0.99,"box":[0.12,0.23,0.45,0.56]},
            "3":{"class":2,"percent":0.99,"box":[0.52,0.83,0.34,0.59]}
           }
```

and so on like this

Now i need to take the value of key "box" and store in an array.

```
var list = []
list = [[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],[0.12,0.23,0.45,0.56],[0.52,0.83,0.34,0.59]]
```

But, i tried multiple ways to store the array inside the array, but i could able to get like this when i printed the list

```
list = 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.12,0.23,0.45,0.56,0.52,0.83,0.34,0.59
```

Comment: Your JSON is not correct.

Comment: @holydragon Looks good to me

Comment: @Feathercrown Well. It has been edited. It is correct now.

Comment: @holydragon Ah, missed that :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Object.keys (which returns an array of all key of your json) in combination with array’s map to transform your json into a new array:

```
const boxes = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key].box)
```

You can also use Object.values, which is actually nicer in your case:

```
const boxes = Object.values(obj).map(value => value.box)
```

### How it works

`Object.keys` return an array:

```
Object.keys(obj) // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

then you can map over them to get the value of each item:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]) // [{box: [...]}, {box: [...]}, {box: [...]}]
```

then in `array.map`'s callback, you can simply only return the box value:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key].box) // [[...], [...], [...]]
```

---

### Without Object.keys()

```
function getBoxes (object) {
  var boxes = [];
  for (var key in object) {
    if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    boxes.push(object[key].box);
  }
  return boxes;
}

console.log(getBoxes(obj))
```

`for...in` can loop through object's properties, but it'll also loop over inherited properties, therefore we need to guard the loop with `object.hasOwnProperty(key)`.

---

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys): Return an array of all enumerable property names of an object

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values): Return an array of all enumerable values of an object

[array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): Return a new array with each item of the original array transformed in a given callback function

[array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice): Return a shallow copy of the original array

Comment: @Shiva here's a jsbin with your provided obj: https://jsbin.com/sexuqahiqa/edit?js,console

Comment: const boxes = Object.values(obj).map(value => value.box)


but the first method is not storing in array of array which should be like this
[[1,2,3,4],[3,6,7,8],[5,8,9,3]]

Comment: @Shiva I'm not sure if we're looking at the same code? I've made a new one here with exact same function & it returns nested array: https://jsbin.com/cicubuhobo/edit?js,console

Comment: list: 0.27345794439315796,0.5364106297492981,0.4557124972343445,0.7002899050712585

Comment: @Shiva this is what I'm looking at: https://imgur.com/a/uid9Hbi

I messed with the original one a bit and change console.log() to console.log(boxes[0]) which only log out the first value, maybe that's what you're looking at?

Comment: for my json obj its working in this console https://jsbin.com/cicubuhobo/3/edit?js,console
but not in my code editor :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185531/discussion-between-derek-nguyen-and-shiva).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Object.values(obj).map(x=>x.box);
```

```js
var obj = { "1":{"class":2,"percent":0.99,"box":[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]},
            "2":{"class":2,"percent":0.99,"box":[0.12,0.23,0.45,0.56]},
            "3":{"class":2,"percent":0.99,"box":[0.52,0.83,0.34,0.59]}
           } 
           
let list = Object.values(obj).map(x=>x.box);

console.log(JSON.stringify(list))
```

The [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns array of obj values, then we use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over that values (we use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) and create new array  with box values.

Comment: I didn't knew `Object.values` was there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check next example:

**1)** First, use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array with the keys of the object.

**2)** Second, loop on every `key` and access the `box` property of the object associated with every key, then push this `box` property on a new array.

```js
var obj = {
    "1": {"class":2, "percent":0.99, "box":[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]},
    "2": {"class":2, "percent":0.99, "box":[0.12,0.23,0.45,0.56]},
    "3": {"class":2, "percent":0.99, "box":[0.52,0.83,0.34,0.59]}
};

var arrayOfArrays = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
    arrayOfArrays.push(obj[k].box);
});

console.log(arrayOfArrays);
```

Here is (just for fun) another alternative using the [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```js
var obj = {
    "1": {"class":2, "percent":0.99, "box":[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]},
    "2": {"class":2, "percent":0.99, "box":[0.12,0.23,0.45,0.56]},
    "3": {"class":2, "percent":0.99, "box":[0.52,0.83,0.34,0.59]}
};

const reducer = (accumulator, currVal) => {
    accumulator.push(currVal.box);
    return accumulator;
};

arrayOfArrays = Object.values(obj).reduce(reducer, []);

console.log(arrayOfArrays);
```

Comment: I tried the same way but couldn't able to achieve it.